# Add defer or async attribute to dynamically generated script tags via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically putting a script tag to the DOM of my page like this:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

This should generate something like this:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

I just want to put in a `defer` or `async` to this script tag like this:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api" defer async></script>
```

So how do I do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There's no need to add `async` to your `script` tag, since that attribute is [enabled by default](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#dynamic-scripts) for dynamic scripts.

As for `defer`, just as you change the `src` attribute in JavaScript, you can also enable that one like so:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
tag.defer = true;
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) for this.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
tag.setAttribute('defer','');
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Comment: How about `tag.defer = true`?

Comment: The link article on MDN does not say anything about async being the default for dynamic script tags. Can you reference exactly where it does say so?

Comment: Dynamic scripts are created with `async` flag [enabled by default](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer).

Comment: I was able to set defer attribute for dynamic scripts, but couldn't find any difference with it's presence. Can I please know if it will have any effect ?, I mean does it behave like a static script with defer attribute?

Answer (score 1):

In order to load dynamic scripts asynchronously, but execute them in the order of definition, use `script.async = false`:

```
['1.js', '2.js'].forEach(s => {
   const script = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script'));
   script.async = false;
   script.src = s;
});
```

Source: https://web.dev/speed-script-loading/#the-dom-to-the-rescue