# Can I add attributes to the script tags that are created on build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, vuejs2

I made a build of my app and this generated the app script file.

For our client we need to put the defer attribute on the scripts.

Is there an option to add this attribute before building so it generated the script file with the attribute on build?

Maybe a setting in the config/index.js, like adding a ./ before the path of the assets.

Index file after build:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>capsule-grid</title>
<link href=./static/css/app.b61a863ffc65a9cdc414d3295eff7eb5.css 
rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body>
<div id=capsule-grid></div>
<script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/manifest.3ad1d5771e9b13dbdad2.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/vendor.a73abbfdb077dea7910a.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=./static/js/app.2a7cef142bfc9b3954a5.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to add the attribute to the app script file, but before the build.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "myjs.js";
script.setAttribute("defer", "true");
```

Something like this is how you can apply attributes via javascript. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289602/add-defer-or-async-attribute-to-dynamically-generated-script-tags-via-javascript) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, do you know where these settings are in Vue? Can't seem to find them.