# Can we use async attribute for script loaded dynamically?

Tags: html, css

Can we use `async` attribute to load script asynchronously for script loaded dynamically?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by `script loaded dynamically`?

Comment: Yes.Will “Async” attribute loads script asynchronously when used for a script that is dynamically added to the DOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the "async" attribute/property useful if a script is dynamically added to the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408805/is-the-async-attribute-property-useful-if-a-script-is-dynamically-added-to-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `script loaded dynamically`, if you mean adding javascript code dynamically to your page, then the answer is **No**.

`async` attribute can only be used on loading external scripts that are referred to via a URL specified in `src` attribute.

> The async attribute is only for external scripts (and should only be used if the src attribute is present)

Example, You can load only scripts like this asyncronously

```
 <script src="external-file.js" async></script>
```

Comment: What about something like `script = document.createElement('script');script.async = true;script.src = "url";`? This is an external script but it's created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting point.

Here is an example, some Similar StackOverflow questions, and jQuery Document link For use of Async attribute

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Async Test Attribute</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="async_demo.js" async></script>
    <h2>Welcome to Demo!</h2>
    <script>
        console.log('HELLO NON-async');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

async_demo.js

```
console.log('HELLO Async');
```

Screencast for above code: https://hareen-nipl.tinytake.com/sf/MzEwNzYzOV85MzEzNTgz

**Async jQuery** : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-async-vs-html5-script-async

**W3School Document**: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp

**Similar StackOverflow questions**

1. [Add defer or async attribute to dynamically generated script tags via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289602/add-defer-or-async-attribute-to-dynamically-generated-script-tags-via-javascript/41289721)
2. [Is the "async" attribute/property useful if a script is dynamically added to the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408805/is-the-async-attribute-property-useful-if-a-script-is-dynamically-added-to-the)

Please comment down below if you have any questions for the same.

Comment: How is this loading the script dynamically?